# How to generate an executable from an llvm::Module?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

I want to write a C++ function that takes an `llvm::Module`, which is already linked, and output it to an executable file. It should use the llvm/clang API rather than forking a process and invoking the command-line clang.

After looking through the llvm/clang source code, the closest thing I've found is to output a `Module` to a .o file. For example, the llc tool (tools/llc/llc.cpp) accomplishes this by calling `TargetMachine::addPassesToEmitFile(...)`.

An alternative would be to write the `Module` to a .bc file, then create a `CompilerInstance` and call `ExecuteCompilerInvocation` (as in tools/clang/tools/driver/cc1_main.cpp). But then there's the overhead of file I/O.

So, am I asking for something possible, or must I fall back on the alternative?

**Edit:** (Of course this is possible. It happens *somewhere* in the clang source code, I just can't find it.)

Comment: Some copy-pasting from `llc` might do the job.

Comment: I don't think so. `llc` can generate a .o file but not an executable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not possible! `clang` does not create the executable itself. It invokes `ld`.

Found it in tools/clang/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp. In the `ConstructJob` functions for the various platforms (`darwin::Link::ConstructJob`, `solaris::Link::ConstructJob`, etc.), it does this:

```
const char *Exec =
    Args.MakeArgString(getToolChain().GetProgramPath("ld"));
  C.addCommand(new Command(JA, *this, Exec, CmdArgs));
```

(For `visualstudio::Link::ConstructJob`, it instead invokes `link.exe`.)

**Edit:** In retrospect, it would have been faster to find this out by tracing `clang`'s system calls with `dtruss` (Mac) or `strace` (Linux).

**Edit:** I ended up using the Clang driver API for building and linking. I wrote up some [example code](http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api).

Comment: clang invokes ld on... what? An object file? How do you generate the object file?

Comment: @andrewrk Maybe a bit late but LLVM can create an object file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my compile function, which compiles the `Module` to an object file and then invokes the Clang++ compilation API to generate an executable.

I don't know if it correctly answers your question, as the object file exists momentarily and is just deleted afterwards (last line)
An optimization is of course to do it all in-memory.
The constructor of `clang::driver::Driver` does have a "Virtual File System" optional argument, which can probably be used.

```
#include "clang/Driver/Driver.h"
#include "clang/Driver/Compilation.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/TextDiagnosticPrinter.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetOptions.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/Support/FileSystem.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetRegistry.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Support/Host.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetMachine.h"

using namespace llvm;
using namespace llvm::sys;


void writeModuleToFile(Module *module)
{
    auto TargetTriple = getDefaultTargetTriple();
    InitializeAllTargetInfos();
    InitializeAllTargets();
    InitializeAllTargetMCs();
    InitializeAllAsmParsers();
    InitializeAllAsmPrinters();

    std::string Error;
    auto Target = TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(TargetTriple, Error);
    auto CPU = "generic";
    auto Features = "";

    TargetOptions opt;
    auto RM = Optional<Reloc::Model>();
    auto TargetMachine = Target->createTargetMachine(TargetTriple, CPU, Features, opt, RM);

    module->setDataLayout(TargetMachine->createDataLayout());
    module->setTargetTriple(TargetTriple);

    auto Filename = "output.o";
    std::error_code EC;
    raw_fd_ostream dest(Filename, EC, sys::fs::OF_None);

    legacy::PassManager pass;
    auto FileType = CGFT_ObjectFile;

    if (TargetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, dest, nullptr, FileType))
    {
        errs() << "TargetMachine can't emit a file of this type";
        return;
    }
    pass.run(*module);
    dest.flush();

    IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticOptions> DiagOpts = new clang::DiagnosticOptions;
    clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter *DiagClient = new clang::TextDiagnosticPrinter(errs(), &*DiagOpts);
    IntrusiveRefCntPtr<clang::DiagnosticIDs> DiagID(new clang::DiagnosticIDs());
    clang::DiagnosticsEngine Diags(DiagID, &*DiagOpts, DiagClient);
    clang::driver::Driver TheDriver("/usr/bin/clang++-12", TargetTriple, Diags);

    auto args = ArrayRef<const char *>{"-g", "output.o", "-o", "main"};

    std::unique_ptr<clang::driver::Compilation> C(TheDriver.BuildCompilation(args));

    if (C && !C->containsError())
    {
        SmallVector<std::pair<int, const clang::driver::Command *>, 4> FailingCommands;
        TheDriver.ExecuteCompilation(*C, FailingCommands);
    }

    remove(Filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`llvm-ld` does what you need when passed the `-native` flag.</strike>

`llvm-ld` has been removed in LLVM 3.1, but the `clang` driver [should be able to replace its function](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#tools_changes). You may start there.

Comment: True, but unfortunately `llvm-ld` accomplishes this by invoking `gcc`.

Comment: llvm-ld has been removed in LLVM 3.1, and they suggest to use clang directly instead to codegen/link bitcode files into an executable (see http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#tools_changes)

Comment: Re: your edit -- As I said in my question, I searched the clang driver code. I found code to turn a .bc file into an executable, but I'm looking for something that can turn an in-memory Module into an executable.