# Generate Executable from llvm::Module

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

My question is kinda similar to this one: [How to generate an executable from an llvm::Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657529/how-to-generate-an-executable-from-an-llvmmodule). But as the answeres there are from 2012, and I'm not sure if anything has changed.

So I've got an LLVM::Module and want to produce an executable from it. I know that I can build an object file from it and invoke a linker on that .o file to get an executable, but I don't want the I/O overhead of reading and writing a intermediate .o file.

I'm wondering if there is an API in the LLVM project that I can use to generate a exec. from a module. Is the [llvm::Linker class](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Linker.html#a5a864cc4d71e0234e9f8d786f8716804) maybe a good point to start?

Comment: It can be done, but really, the overhead of reading/writing a single file is negligible. The Linker class operates on IR rather than native code so it won't be right for you. You might want to start either with lld/gold/mold or with the [ORCJIT](https://llvm.org/docs/ORCv2.html) and write code that creates an executable from the in-memory native code that ORCJIT creates. The emacs undump utility might contain code you can use. Frankly, it sounds like a lot of work to save a thousandth of a second.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to orcjit. Although I decided, that (as you said) the additional word is just not worth it, I'll probably still check out orcjit an see what it has to offer.